# How to access the glue?

Tags: xetex, tex-core

Consider the following document run by `xelatex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\XeTeXinterchartokenstate = 1
\newXeTeXintercharclass \mycharclassa
\newXeTeXintercharclass \mycharclassb
\XeTeXcharclass `\a \mycharclassa
\XeTeXcharclass `\b \mycharclassa
\XeTeXcharclass `\c \mycharclassa
\XeTeXcharclass `\x \mycharclassb
\XeTeXcharclass `\y \mycharclassb
\XeTeXcharclass `\z \mycharclassb
\XeTeXinterchartoks \mycharclassa \mycharclassb = {{\color{red}\leaders\hrule height 10pt\hskip0pt plus 0.5em}}
\begin{document}
abcxyzaxbyczabxcyzabcxyzaxbyczabxcyzabcxyzaxbyczabxcyz%
abcxyzaxbyczabxcyzabcxyzaxbyczabxcyzabcxyzaxbyczabxcyz%
abcxyzaxbyczabxcyzabcxyzaxbyczabxcyzabcxyzaxbyczabxcyz%
abcxyzaxbyczabxcyzabcxyzaxbyczabxcyzabcxyzaxbyczabxcyz%
abcxyzaxbyczabxcyzabcxyzaxbyczabxcyzabcxyzaxbyczabxcyz%
abcxyzaxbyczabxcyzabcxyzaxbyczabxcyzabcxyzaxbyczabxcyz%
abcxyzaxbyczabxcyzabcxyzaxbyczabxcyzabcxyzaxbyczabxcyz%
abcxyzaxbyczabxcyzabcxyzaxbyczabxcyzabcxyzaxbyczabxcyz%
abcxyzaxbyczabxcyzabcxyzaxbyczabxcyzabcxyzaxbyczabxcyz%
abcxyzaxbyczabxcyzabcxyzaxbyczabxcyzabcxyzaxbyczabxcyz%
abcxyzaxbyczabxcyzabcxyzaxbyczabxcyzabcxyzaxbyczabxcyz%
abcxyzaxbyczabxcyzabcxyzaxbyczabxcyzabcxyzaxbyczabxcyz%
abcxyzaxbyczabxcyzabcxyzaxbyczabxcyzabcxyzaxbyczabxcyz%
abcxyzaxbyczabxcyzabcxyzaxbyczabxcyzabcxyzaxbyczabxcyz%
abcxyzaxbyczabxcyzabcxyzaxbyczabxcyzabcxyzaxbyczabxcyz%
abcxyzaxbyczabxcyzabcxyzaxbyczabxcyzabcxyzaxbyczabxcyz%
abcxyzaxbyczabxcyzabcxyzaxbyczabxcyzabcxyzaxbyczabxcyz%
abcxyzaxbyczabxcyzabcxyzaxbyczabxcyzabcxyzaxbyczabxcyz%
abcxyzaxbyczabxcyzabcxyzaxbyczabxcyzabcxyzaxbyczabxcyz%
abcxyzaxbyczabxcyzabcxyzaxbyczabxcyzabcxyzaxbyczabxcyz%
abcxyzaxbyczabxcyzabcxyzaxbyczabxcyzabcxyzaxbyczabxcyz%
\end{document}
```

When you look at the output, some of the red `\hrule`s are thicker than the others. What parameter does define this variable thickness? Can one access it as a dimen?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You're inserting glue between letters, and justification does the rest, stretching the glue where necessary.

Comment: the glue stretch here is (by design) not accessible from within TeX to avoid exposing machine dependent arithmetic

Comment: @egreg Thank you. I would like to know if it is possible to access this variable glue (variable thickness of the red `\hrule`s) as a dimen. I wish to know exactly how much glue is inserted at each place.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle That is too bad. TeX has its limitations then like any other tools after all.

Comment: the glue that is inserted is what you specified `0pt plus 0.5em` all the glue in a single line will stretch to the same amount so if you know which letters of each class are on a line you can calculate the stretch

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Suppose that I did not have the `\leaders\hrule height 10pt\hskip0pt plus 0.5em` part in my code, then is it possible to replace it with a conditional test `\ifdim\somedimen>0pt \hrule height 10pt width \somedimen\fi` where `\somedimen` is the needed variable dimen so that all lines are justified without any badness?

Comment: no you need stretchy glue to do the justification , the paragraph is taken as a whole and broken into lines and then only after that any stretch glue on each line is stretched to justify the line, so in your case all glue on a line stretches by the same amount but you can not know that amount until the lines have been broken (and the position of the linebreaks depends on the glue added, so you can not do the linebreaking then add glue as without the glue/leaders ther would be no linebreaking)

Comment: I think you may be able to access this glue in LuaTeX (maybe in `post_linebreak_filter` or even later), though you'll of course have to change the XeTeXcharclass mechanism.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The final thickness is not available, because it comes from the justification algorithm.

Leaders behave the same as glue. The end result of your input is the same as having

```
\spaceskip=0pt plus 0.5em
```

and, an extract from the first line,

```
abc xyza xb yc zab xc yzabc xyza xb yc zab ...
```

The justification algorithm will stretch some lines so that they fill the line, after having chosen the line breaks.

Instead of the spaces you have rules, but it's really the same thing. And, no, the amount of stretching is not available during processing, but it can only be seen with `\showoutput` (or similar methods) in the log file.

Comment: Thanks. Suppose that I did not have the `\leaders\hrule height 10pt\hskip0pt plus 0.5em` part in my code, then is it possible to replace it with a conditional test `\ifdim\somedimen>0pt \hrule height 10pt width \somedimen\fi` where `\somedimen` is the needed variable dimen so that all lines are justified without any badness?

Comment: @CazSandison How? The lines have different natural width, so justification needs different amount of stretching for each line.